# Unable to find the pricing and limit for the server to server notification

Tags: in-app-purchase, apple-push-notifications, subscription, in-app-subscription, server-to-server

While using the server to server notification for checking the subscriber's subscription status I am unable to find the pricing and limit of the server to server notification
I have gone through the documentation regarding the server to server notification for apple but didn't find any solutions regarding it .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

App Store Server Notification does not tell you the pricing and expiration dates of subscriptions.

> App Store Server Notifications notifies you in real-time when the status of in-app purchases and refunds changes.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications

Therefore, to know the pricing and expiration dates, You have to do the following things.

**How to know the price**

If you want to know the price of in-app purchase products, you should implement the request of product information in your app using [SKProductRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproductsrequest). Then in the [productsRequest(_:didReceive:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproductsrequestdelegate/1506070-productsrequest) function of SKProductsRequestDelegate, you can get the product information and its price.

**How to know the expiration dates**

If you want to know the expiration dates of subscriptions, you have to verify receipt by submitting an HTTP POST request to this URL `https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt`.
The response body contains [the latest receipt information](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/responsebody/latest_receipt_info), and there is a field called `expires_date` in it. This is what you want to know.